# How to get the closed tab in safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, tabs, safari-extension

I am catching the "close" event for tab, but how I can which tab was closed?

```
safari.application.addEventListener("close", function(e){
     // all e.target values are undefined, which is not helpful..    
},true)
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment the event is captured, the properties of e.target (the closed tab) are not undefined. I'm guessing you're using something like `console.log(e.target)` and then examining the logged object in the console. You're seeing undefined properties then because the event has already finished propagating.

Try this instead:

```
safari.application.addEventListener("close", function (e) {
    if (e.target instanceof SafariBrowserTab) {
        console.log(e.target.title, e.target.url);
    }
}, true);
```

You will see that the tab's properties are still defined at the moment of event capture, so you can compare them to previously stored values; or, if you have previously assigned the desired tab to a variable, you can even compare e.target itself to that variable.